# How to display a chapter / section reference in the pattern (chapter n section m), where n is the chapter number and m the section path

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters

I have the following content structure:

```
\chapter{Kapitel 1}
\label{ch:c_1}
\section{Abschnitt 1}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt 1}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt 2}
\label{ch:u_a_2}
```

The goal is a chapter reference. When I want to refer to a chapter (**ch:c_1**) the output should look like this:

*In Chapter 1 you can see...*

When I want to refer to a section or subsection (**ch:u_a_2**) the output should look like this:

*In Chapter 1 Section 1.2 you can see...*

Is there any package I can use?

**The Answer** 
With the package *cleveref* you can write `cref{ch:c_1} cref{ch:u_a_2}`
If you want to change the naming of the default ones you can use *\crefname* in the following way (german example):

```
\crefname{chapter}{Kapitel}{Kapitel}
\crefname{section}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
```

Comment: `\Cref{ch:c_1} \Cref{ch:u_a_2}`, using the `cleveref` package in conjunction with the `ngerman` option of the `babel` package. The naming scheme of your labels is error-prone, however. Make sure to load the `cleveref` package as the last one of all

Comment: And this is surely a duplicate

Comment: I thought it would be possible in just one command. Thank you everything worked fine. Is there a possibility to change the naming of _chapter_ and _section_?

Comment: As I wrote: Use the `ngerman` option to the document class and `babel` and you will get `Kapitel` etc. Please see the manual as well -- reading it does not hurt ;-)

Comment: The plural form of Kapitel is Kapitel, not Kapitel, as well Abschnitte and not `Abschnitts` ;-)

Comment: Okay you're right, why I am not able to read^^ And I thought the second parameter was for the genitive^^

Comment: @dodo978 Don't include your answer in the question. Instead, post it as a separate answer. It is [120% fine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).